# How to troubleshoot audio problem in Fedora?

Tags: fedora, audio, pulseaudio, alsa

How to troubleshoot my audio problem so i can fix it ? i don't know where to start and what causing it. Here's some information i can give, and will gladly provide more if anyone can help / guide me :( , i don't add my dmesg yet, because i don't know what should i provide from it

the symptomps to provide this error is random. Deleting ~/.config/pulse folder can temporary fix the problem, but in the future it can back to error again

i'm using asus-g751 because mine was G752VY. It's the same card

```
sudo cat /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
options snd_hda_intel model=asus-g751
```

```
aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC668 Analog [ALC668 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: ALC668 Digital [ALC668 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

```
pactl info
Server String: /run/user/1000/pulse/native
Library Protocol Version: 35
Server Protocol Version: 35
Is Local: yes
Client Index: 45
Tile Size: 65472
User Name: jeremykenn
Host Name: asus-pc
Server Name: pulseaudio
Server Version: 15.0
Default Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
Default Channel Map: front-left,front-right
Default Sink: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo
Default Source: alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo
```

[image]

Comment: What is the actual problem? The Dummy Output device as shown in the screenshot? I assume so, but it's probably good to describe what's actually not working in the question itself.

Comment: @mattdm Sorry, i'm still confused before so not sure i can explain my actual problem. But after some troubleshooting, i found the problem is because my waterfox is using pipewire and it's interfacing my audio(pulseaudio).  (I still use pulseaudio in Fedora 35, because my jack audio not work if i use pipewire).

My temporary solution is to close all program that use audio, and run fuser -v /dev/snd/* to list the process. Then i kill the pipewire process id, and if fuser -v /dev/snd/* empty, i'll just run pulseaudio -k

Comment: Let me rephrase. I'm not asking what the root cause of the problem is. I'm asking — what trouble are you experiencing? What are you doing, what do you expect to happen, and what is happening instead?

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/676192/117549

Answer (score 1):

For me running `sudo dnf swap --allowerasing pulseaudio pipewire-pulseaudio` as suggested at https://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=2016253 worked.

After a reboot sound was working as usual.